# Find planes orthogonal to a known plane

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra

I was hoping to get some help here.  I'm a geologist so my math background isn't as strong as it should be.  I have a geological fault that I've digitized in a CAD program.  I've placed three representative points on the fault plane and extracted those coordinate points.  I've found the unit vector of that plane using the following code:

```
p1 = np.array([503562, 2811504, 1771], dtype='float64')
p2 = np.array([504122, 2810766, 1820], dtype='float64')
p3 = np.array([504325, 2811311, 1042], dtype='float64')

#  Calculate vectors
v1 = p3 - p1
v2 = p2 - p1

#  Find the cross product (vector normal to the plane)
cp = np.cross(v1, v2)

#  Assign to a, b and c for components of plane equation
a, b, c = cp

#  Calculate d component with a dot product and the following equation:
#    a*x3 + b*y3 + c*z3 = d
d = np.dot(cp, p3)

#  Find the unit vector
uv = cp / (cp**2).sum()**0.5
```

This vector represents a plane which is my maximum direction of continuity (a geological term).  I need to get the two planes which are at 90 degree angles to the plane defined above.  I know this is probably quite simple in terms of linear algebra but I'm at a loss right now.  I eventually need this to get the strike and dip of the three planes of continuity defined above.

**Edit:**  added a picture for clarity

The blue feature is a fault. The green rugby ball is my search ellipse. I need to figure out the planes which are defined by that shape. I used those green points digitized on the fault to calculate the first plane. I don't know how to get the other two

[image: fault and search ellipse]

Comment: There are an infinity of those. Are you happy with any? If not please clarify...

Comment: You mean: you want to find two other orthogonal planes that are orthogonal to your already known plane (i.e. fault)? If yes, it is a ill-posed problem and there would be infinite planes that will satisfy your condition. You need to have more geometrical restrictions (if it is possible or makes sense due to your geology knowledge) to narrow down those infinite set of planes into unique ones.

Comment: I had this feature in mind (in my case, I have the black plane):  http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/sgrais/images/PlanesSpace/planes.jpg

Comment: You're picture doesn't help. You can rotate it by any angle and still have a valid frame...

Comment: @user115657 OK, so your problem does not have unique solution.

Comment: By the way, your question is not related to programming I believe... At the best, it could be transferred to Mathematics.SE...

Comment: I guess the tilt would be 0 so that should constrain the plane, no?  I have an approximate strike and dip of 330 and -70.

Comment: "Tilt would be 0" tilt about what? Cause you are talking about 3D space, angles are a bit more complicated and it's better to talk about normal vectors instead of angles.

Comment: I've added a picture to the original post for clarity.  The blue feature is a fault.  The green rugby ball is my search ellipse.  I need to figure out the planes which are defined by that shape.  I used those green points digitized on the fault to calculate the first plane.  I don't know how to get the other two.

Comment: @user115657, reading your comment (which I copied  to the question) and looking into the image I still don't get what planes you mean and how the rugby ball is related to the task.

Comment: You must fill the gap from geology to math,  i e define what is strike and dip. probably other points are necessary, or  p1 p2 p3 have particular properties to define an unique ellipse.

Answer (score 3):

So assuming you are happy with any such planes:

You already have `cp` defining your "continuity plane".
`ortho1 = np.cross(v1, cp)` will give you one orthogonal direction to `cp` i.e one of your possible requested planes.
Then `ortho2 = np.cross(cp, ortho1)` will give you the second corresponding one.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, this is what I believe you want:

- For the strike, you want the intersection of your plane and a horizontal plane (so cross product of your unit vector and a (0,0,1) vector.
- For the dip, you want the cross product of your plane's unit vector and the strike's unit vector.

I agree with other commenters - maybe sort out the math on your own... then you can come to  stackoverflow if you have problems implementing it in Python :)

Comment: I do want the intersection with the horizontal plane.  I should be able to get it from there.  Thanks!